# How 20K objects can be efficiently saved into CoreData in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I wondered if there is an efficient way to save 20.000 objects into CoreData. Currently saving them takes about 2 minutes and it would be great if I could make it faster.

Now I'm doing the saving in the next way:

```
for serverCar in serverCars {
    let dbObjectCar = DBObjectCar.createWithAttributes(["carNbr" : serverCar.carNbr! as AnyObject], context: context) as DBObjectCar
    self.handleCar(serverCar: serverCar, dbObjectCar: dbObjectCar, defaultContext: context)
}
```

where

```
class func createWithAttributes(_ attributes: [String : AnyObject], context: NSManagedObjectContext = DBContext.defaultContext) -> Self {
    let object = create(context: context)
    if attributes.count > 0 {
        object.setValuesForKeys(attributes)
    }
    return object
}
```

`create` method is:

```
class func create(context: NSManagedObjectContext = DBContext.defaultContext) -> Self {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)
    let object = self.init(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)

    return object 
}
```

and

```
fileprivate func handleCar(serverCar: ServerCar, dbObjectCar: DBObjectCar, defaultContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    _ = Mapper.Map(serverCar, dbo: dbObjectCar, context: defaultContext)
}
```

and `Mapper` is:

```
class func Map(_ serverCar: ServerCar, dbObjectCar: DBObjectCar, context : NSManagedObjectContext) -> DBObjectCar {
    if let carNbr = serverCar.carNbr {
        serverCar.setValue(carNbr, forKey: "carNbr")
    }

    return serverCar
}
```

and also I want to present my objects classes:

```
open class DBObjectCar: NSManagedObject { ... }
struct ServerCar : JSON { ... }
```

So the main problem for me is, how can I make this saving 20.000 car objects faster? I will really appreciate your answers!
If you have any questions - please ask me, maybe I forgot mentioning something or sharing some pieces of my code.

Comment: If you want to supply the 20000 objects to your users you can pre-populate a Core Data repository and ship it with your app.

Comment: @Magnas no. If you noticed I have `Server` objects, so I'm getting all my values from the server and I have to solve this problem dynamically, without any pre-installations

Comment: At what point are you committing (save) the car objects? Committing is very expensive time wise, and could be taking a large amount of time if each car object is saved individually.

Comment: @bobnoble I've just updated my question and added `create` method implementation. So I'm saving each car inside of `createWithAttributes` and which I'm calling for each car in my array

Comment: @J.Doe; You can create the array of Entities and save all in one go?

Comment: @Brandon you think it can increase the performance? Is there any batch insert operation?

Comment: @Brandon actually I'm just creating objects and putting them into the context and save them at the very end. I just checked it

Comment: I'd start with Instruments with each of the following templates: Time Profiler, Core Data, Allocations, and maybe File Activity. I'd also try hand-writing this without any functions in one hard-coded for-loop just to see how fast you can do it with the fewest moving parts. Of particular note, you create entityDescription 20k times when you only need it once I think. I'm a little confused by the handleCar/Map dance, and it feels like `carNbr` is getting set twice.